# How to send selected messages using checkbox to a particular no?

Tags: android, listview, sms, custom-adapter

first i'm fetching all messages to my app to be store in listview then **I'm selecting messages from listview using checkboxes** and wish to **send these selected sms to a single number that is predefined** and wish to **use the selected sms as body of message to be send to single no.** but the ***problem*** is that the ***message sent contains complete listview messages not the selected one.*** So please someone ***correct me where i'm wrong in code*** as i wish to **send only selected messages not the complete listview items(messages)**

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

Button send;
ListView listViewSMS;
Cursor cursor;
SMSListAdapter smsListAdapter;
Context context;
SharedPreferences prefs=null;
ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> adapter;
List<SMSListModel> list = new ArrayList<SMSListModel>();
TextView textViewSMSSender, textViewSMSBody;
int i;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);

    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnproperty);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);

    textViewSMSSender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
    textViewSMSBody=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

    smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this,getModel());
    listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);
    listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvSMSSend);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.cbSelect);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}

private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.isChecked())
        return "is checked";
    else
        return "is not checked";
}

private List<SMSListModel> getModel() {

    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        for(i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i)){
                list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))));
            }
        }
    }


    return list;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    if( v == send){
        mDialog();

    }



public void mDialog(){



     // Show The Dialog with Selected SMS 
     AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
     dialog.setTitle("Message App");
     dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
     dialog.setMessage("Count : ");
     dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         {
             String phoneNo = "111";
             if(list.size()>0){
                 for(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                     if(list.get(i).isSelected()){

                         try{
                             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                             for(SMSListModel p: list){
                                 builder.append(p.toString());
                                 builder.append('\n');
                             }
                            String sms = builder.toString();
                             smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         }

                         catch (Exception e){
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             e.printStackTrace();

                         }
                         dialog.dismiss();

                 }
              }
            }
         }
     });

     dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
     dialog.show();

}
```

---

```
public class SMSListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> {

private final List<SMSListModel> list;
private final Activity mContext;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public SMSListAdapter(Activity context,List<SMSListModel> list) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.listview_each_item, list);
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textAddress;
    protected TextView textBody;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
        viewHolder.textBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSSend, viewHolder.textAddress);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSBody, viewHolder.textBody);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.cbSelect, viewHolder.checkbox);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.textAddress.setText(list.get(position).getAddress());
    viewHolder.textBody.setText(list.get(position).getBody());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());    

    return convertView;
}
```

---

```
public class SMSListModel {

private String address;
String body;
private boolean selected;

public SMSListModel(String address, String body) {
    this.address = address;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String toString(){

    return body;
}}
```

Comment: What u want actually? be more specific

Comment: I want to select multiple rows and perform delete or send all to specific no @ MD

Comment: Go to this link for your achievement [multiple-row-item-listview](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/multiple-row-item-deleted-from-listview.html) and [android-multiple-selection-listview/](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/)

Comment: If you want to select multiple rows then you should use multiple check box selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know why you want to select multiple rows. I mean what exact action you want to perform by selecting multiple rows?

Here is the updated code for you. Please let me know in case you didn't get any code:

```
    ---------------
    package com.example.multiselectlist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

        Button btnDelete;
        ListView listViewSMS;
        Cursor cursor;
        SMSListAdapter smsListAdapter;
        Context context;

        ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> adapter;
        List<SMSListModel> list = new ArrayList<SMSListModel>();


        int count = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            context=this;
            listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);
            btnDelete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

            cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

            smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this,getModel());
            listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);
            listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvSMSSend);
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.cbSelect);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
        }

        private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
            if(checkbox.isChecked())
                return "is checked";
            else
                return "is not checked";
        }

        private List<SMSListModel> getModel() {

            if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
                    if(cursor.moveToPosition(i)){
                        list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))));
                    }
                }
            }


            return list;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            switch(id){
                case R.id.buttonDelete:
                    if(list.size()>0){
                        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                            if(list.get(i).isSelected()){
                                list.remove(i);
                            }
                        }

                        smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this,list);
                        smsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);
                    }
                    break;
                    case R.id.buttonSend:
 String contactNum = "+123456789";
            String messageList = "";
            if(list.size()>0){
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                    if(list.get(i).isSelected()){
                        if(messageList.equals(""))
                            messageList = list.get(i).getBody();
                        else
                            messageList = messageList+";"+list.get(i).getBody();
                    }
                }
                Log.v("messageList",""+messageList);
                Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + contactNum);
                Log.d("sendSmsTo",""+sendSmsTo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sendSmsTo);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", messageList);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);    
            }

            }

        }
    }
```

---

`SMSListModel` class:

```
    package com.example.multiselectlist;

    public class SMSListModel {

        private String address;
        String body;
        private boolean selected;

        public SMSListModel(String address, String body) {
            this.address = address;
            this.body = body;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public String getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
    }
```

---

`SMSListAdapter` class:
        package com.example.multiselectlist;

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SMSListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> {

        private final List<SMSListModel> list;
        private final Activity mContext;
        boolean checkAll_flag = false;
        boolean checkItem_flag = false;

        public SMSListAdapter(Activity context,List<SMSListModel> list) 
        {
            super(context, R.layout.listview_each_item, list);
            mContext = context;
            this.list = list;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            protected TextView textAddress;
            protected TextView textBody;
            protected CheckBox checkbox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
                viewHolder.textBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);
                viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
                viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                                list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                            }
                        });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSSend, viewHolder.textAddress);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSBody, viewHolder.textBody);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.cbSelect, viewHolder.checkbox);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

            viewHolder.textAddress.setText(list.get(position).getAddress());
            viewHolder.textBody.setText(list.get(position).getBody());
            viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());    

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

---

`xml`:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Delete" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvSMS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonDelete" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSMSSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cbSelect"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbSelect"
            android:text="9998698700" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSMSBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvSMSSend"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSMSSend"
            android:text="body" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Alright. You can do like: 1. Keep checkbox (avoid recycling issue) on each list item. 2. Create a Global variable ArrayList which will store selected ids. 3. On checkbox clicked, store each ids. 4. Put a delete button above the layout on clicking of which delete your stored ids. If you still didn't get me share your code, I will do it for you.

Comment: I am updating my SDK manager. I will get back to you after 2-3 hours.

Comment: Please find the necessary code edited above. Please let me know in case you didn't get any part from that.

Comment: Thanks :) Please mark this post as resolved so that other can take benifit of it.

Comment: To see the code for "SMS to multiple contacts/phone numbers", please check the line from "case R.id.buttonSend:". I have edited the code.

Comment: This time you try yourself and let me know :). I will give a +1 to you if you do it.

Comment: it uses predefined number and there is a problem in sms body of new message it take complete inbox messages but not the selected one can you resolve this

Comment: Okay. I will resolve. But please answer in case a user select multiple message then what should happen? Will message body of all selected message will be sent?

Comment: yes only selected message body need to be sent but with this all inbox message body are sent

Comment: Okay I understand. It can be done that if a user select one message that particular message can be sent. But what if if you check on multiple messages on the list and press send button?

Comment: then all the checked messages need to be send

Comment: messages with Phone number are displaying instead of their name saved in contact list

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
yourListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

To choose multiple items, remember that its interface depend on you creating it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_selected" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@color/list_bg" />
</selector>
```

Comment: how to change background color of selected row @ Aashir

Comment: Answer updated. You set that XML as the background for your row snd it will adjust accordingly,  also change the backgrounds to the ones you have.

Comment: do i need to create another xml in layout folder for the above code

Comment: In the drawable folder.

Comment: with what name in drawable folder and what code to write in main xml where listview is declare and what is "@drawable/list_item_bg_selcted"

Comment: The name is your choice.. set it as the background of your custom row view xml, like android:background="@drawable/the name you chose". And like I said,replace them with the color / Image you want the row to have when its selected and when it's not.