# How to fetch multiple text message details?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I'm creating this post to get help. I am developing an application which sends `incoming text sms`.What I'm doing is fetching `incoming message body, date and time` and send it as new message. for sending purpose I'm using `sms manager`. I'm able to get multiple message body using `checkboxes` and creating a `list` of selected messages. But the problem is in getting their date and time.

Code for array list of selected messages:

```
private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
                list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Code to send selected message body:

```
if(list.size()>0){
   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
   {
       if(list.get(i).isSelected())
       {
        if(body.equals(""))
               body =list.get(i).getBody();

           else
            body =list.get(i).getBody();
         try
         {
             String mbody = "from"+ "dd/mm/yy" +"hh:mm"+body;
             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
             smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, mbody, null, null);
         }                           
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             //Error Occurred if No Messages Selected 
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Look at once and please provide me with proper edits if possible

Comment: try to get Date and Time as per my answer

Comment: @M D But where's your answer ?

Comment: I deleted. I think it's not working so

Comment: @M D will you update answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try like this way:

```
  ArrayList<Object> time = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
                Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String messageDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
                time.add(messageDate);  
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

**Update:** And also change `Date format` like:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String strBody="from "+time.get(position)+body;
```

Comment: @M D I want to fetch received sms date and time and use it a body of new message to be composed

Comment: @Androidbeginner here i got the SMS Date and Display into my ListView. that's it

Comment: @M D my problem is that i want date and time of selected text message to be use in new message body `String mbody`

Comment: @Androidbeginner then it's very simple. convert your message date into string and append into string with body.

Comment: @M D that's what i need for both date and time. Can you please tell me how to do this

Comment: @M D first i need to create array object for time

Comment: @Androidbeginner ohkk. My deleted Answer also worked. then +1 up

Comment: @Androidbeginner ya off course remove ss from `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss` and try

Comment: @M D Can I have date and time to be informat like `dd/mm/yy, Time hh:mm`

Comment: @M D No, `hh:mm` to be followed by `Time`. Like in format `dd/mm/yy Time hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @Androidbeginner hey i dont know about more Pattern so u can go to official [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) where you find more patterns. thnx

Comment: @M D is there any way like when new message received my application `listview` will be automatically populated with `new message received`

Comment: @M D need some more help for the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21427467/3172071). In this all the phone number will be replaced by their contact name. If possible can you tell me how. thx

Comment: I've modify my code but having some problem can you please have a look and correct me . Thanks [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23131866/3172071)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define another member inside your model. here's how you can read date and set it to your model via constructor/setter.

```
private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
SMSListModel model=new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));

String date =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);    
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
    String smsDate = finaldate.toString();

model.setSMSDate(smsDate);
                list.add(model);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Inside your send SMS code logic, just read it from the model and add it to your SMS body

```
list.get(i).getSMSDate();
```

**haven't tested this but you get the point.**