# Error: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed?

Tags: android, android-listview, sms, android-cursor

In my application I'm fetching `inbox messages` from native application to `my application`. Also there are checkboxes to select multiple messages.But the problem arises are no messages are displaying in `listview while running code` and also showing error `android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.`

```
ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> adapter;
List<SMSListModel> list = new ArrayList<SMSListModel>();
TextView textViewSMSSender, textViewSMSBody

 public void getInboxSms() {
    //Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    c = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    //startManagingCursor(c);
     //totalSMS = c.getCount();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

            Log.d("SMSss", "Contact number : "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))+ "\n"
                            + "msg : " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")
                            + "\n"
                            + "Person : "
                            + getContactName(getApplicationContext(),c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
   c.close();

}

public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
            new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
    if(c.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(c.moveToPosition(i))
            {                   
                list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));

            }
        }
    }

    return list;

}
```

SmsListAdapter

```
public class SMSListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> {

private final List<SMSListModel> list;
private final Activity mContext;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public SMSListAdapter(Activity context,List<SMSListModel> list) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.listview_each_item, list);
    Log.d("size of list", ""+list.size());
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textAddress;
    protected TextView textBody;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
        viewHolder.textBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSSend, viewHolder.textAddress);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSMSBody, viewHolder.textBody);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.cbSelect, viewHolder.checkbox);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
    viewHolder.textAddress.setText(list.get(position).getAddress());
    viewHolder.textBody.setText(list.get(position).getBody());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());    
    return convertView;
}}
```

SMSListModel

```
public class SMSListModel {

private String address;
String body;
private boolean selected;

public SMSListModel(String address, String body) {
    this.address = address;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}}
```

[image: Logcat]

Answer (score 1):

cursor "c" is a global variable which you use in these two methods

```
getModel();

getInboxSms();
```

But the problem is you close the cursor in `getInboxSms()` method and try to access same cursor in `getModel()` method.

So remove this line from getInboxSms() method and try.

```
 c.close();
```

Update this method

```
private List<SMSListModel> getModel() {
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        return list;

    }
```

Update your onCreate() Method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        context = this;
        listViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);

        getInboxSms();
        textViewSMSSender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
        textViewSMSBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);
        smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this, getModel());

        listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter); // you forget to add this line
        listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: still messages are not displaying in `listview`

Comment: Error is coming or not?

Comment: is getInboxSms() method print the messages

Comment: No error is showing up and also no messages are displayed on screen

Comment: check my edits for logcat and also no messages are displaying in `listview` when run this code

Comment: tried but still messages are not displaying on screen
I'm fetching messages from native application to mine that need to be display in listview. But when I run my code the messages are not displaying

Comment: where you setting an adapter for list?

Comment: I'm adding data to `array list` but not setting any adapter for that list . can you please tell me how and where I need to do that. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50878/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-android-beginner)

Comment: yesterday my net was down. Can you please tell me now how to solve that.

Comment: but still names are not displying only phone numbers are there

Comment: please check chat discussion there i'm putting complete code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to close the cursor in both your method that is

```
public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) 
 public void getInboxSms()
```

You can try to close the cursor when all your operations are completed

Comment: just removed the line where cursor are closing after that still messages are not displaying...

Comment: are you sure that you have messages?? Try to get the messages(or better a single message) for a single contact. See if it works. If not there must be some flaw in the logic

Comment: Yes, I've messages in my inbox