# get the SMS Sender Contact saved name when retrieving messages using “content://sms/inbox”

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-contentresolver

In my App I'm `retrieving message` from native `Messaging app` and displaying them in `listView`.

```
Retrieving messages works perfectly fine, but the problem is that Phone Number are 
displaying instead of Sender Contact(Person) saved name.
```

Code used to fetch messages from inbox is :

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

So, is there any way which i can achieve the same(name instead of phone numbers).

[**Link for complete code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21427467/3172071)

Comment: before post search on google/stack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7387359/1765530